# read a webpage programmatically and extract some information

Tags: java, web-scraping, bufferedreader

I want to access a webpage programmatically and extract some information from it.

I want to log in to some website through `Java` code and make the server feel that the request is actually coming from a real browser.

I am almost there albeit one problem: the website requires a `parameter - "sessid"` to be passed with to be passed with every request which keeps on changing with every request.

For e.g when I first access the page the `sessid=90334` and at the next page its like `sessid=78204`.

Therefore the `url` I pass should contain the value of `sessid` otherwise the authentication fails: `www.somesite.com/somepage.php?sessid=75749`.

The webpage contains one `<input>` tag which holds the value of `sessid` and i have to retrieve the value of that tag.

How can i do that? The tag is like this:

`<input type="hidden" name="sessid" value="69529">`

I am able to read the whole webpage successfully using the following code:

```
   BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
    }
```

Comment: Would it be more suitable to use http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` method of `StringBuilder` class:

```
    String startInputFragment = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sessid\" value=\"";
    int startIdx = response.indexOf(startInputFragment);
    if (startIdx >= 0) {
        int endIdx = response.indexOf("\">", startIdx);
        String val = response.substring(startIdx + startInputFragment.length(),
                endIdx);
        System.out.println("-->" + val + "<--");
    } else {
        //tag not found: you may throw an ex or do something else
    }
```